# Appending bits to increase the size of a char

Tags: c++

Is there any way I can append the size of a particular variable? For instance, if I have:

```
static_cast<char>(0x0147)
```

an 8 bit char and I want to increase it to say 16 bits without changing the data type, is that possible?

Comment: The data type very firmly specifies the size of an object.

Comment: Could you supply a more comprehensive example? What you are currently presenting doesn't make too much sense in the context of a statically typed language such as C++. Are you thinking in terms of `std::variant`?

Comment: Why not use `std::uint16_t` for a 16 bits unsigned?

Comment: There's `auto i = 0x0147` which makes it _enough_ bits. But it very much changes the data type. The problem with this question appears to be a rather fuzzy understanding of the type system. All chars have the same size, even if they hold different values.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted and people are freaking out here lol don't overthink it Lightness's answer was perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Rob: I agree, this is an intriguing question, and the current single answer ain't so bad either. Upped and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The size of the object is not only related to its type; the size is *defined* by the type.

You cannot change one and not the other.

Just initialize a new `int16_t` from this `char` if that's what you want.

Or, you could have a `vector<char>` and add new elements to this collection as needed.

(Shifting has nothing to do with it; that's about transforming *data*.)

Comment: So shift changes the data itself then? So I could alter 0x0147 to a different value with shift? You mentioned initializing a new int16_t from the char. Do you just mean int16_t newInt = static_cast<char>(0x0147) sort of thing?

Comment: @Rob a shift is an *arithmetic* operation, very similar to a multiplication (or division) `0x0147 << 4` is `0x1470`, which is the same as `0x0147 * 16` (2 to the 4th power)

Comment: @Rob Just `int16_t newInt = 0x0147;` will be fine mate .. your computer knows what to do